# android iIllegal argument exception service not registered on unbind

Tags: android, android-service

Ok I have looked at a lot of questions but unable to find a solution...

Keep getting the "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered:"

**Note that the "onServiceConnected" method of ServiceConnection is NOT being called....**

This is what I have (ignore all the Log.e's.. I dont really know anyother way to find out which functions are called without debugging):

How service is declared in manifest:

```
<service android:name="com.example.servicestry.MyService" android:enabled="true"/>
```

My activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    MyService mBoundService=null;


    public ServiceConnection mConnection;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        mConnection=new ServiceConnection(){

            @Override
            public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
                Log.e("onserviceconnected","");
                mBoundService = ((MyService.LocalBinder)service).getService();

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "local service connected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.e("onservicedisconnected","");
                mBoundService=null; 
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "local service disconnected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        };

        this.doBindService();

        Timer timer=new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new RemindTask(), 3000);

    } 

    public void doUnbindService(){
        Log.e("doUnbindService","");
        unbindService(mConnection);
    }
    public void doBindService(){


        boolean b=bindService(new Intent(this,MyService.class),mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        if(b){
            Toast.makeText(this, "binding service", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "binding service FAILED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        this.doUnbindService();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    public class RemindTask extends TimerTask{

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "this is runner", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.e("runner run","r");
            doUnbindService();

        }

    }
}
```

My service class

package com.example.servicestry;

```
public class MyService extends Service{
    LocalBinder mBinder= new LocalBinder();;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();

        Log.e("binder create","ASDF");


    } 

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent i,int flag, int startId){
        Log.e("on start command","D");
        return super.onStartCommand(i, flag, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.e("DEST","");
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.e("onbind","ASDF");


        return mBinder;

    }

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        MyService getService() {


            return MyService.this;
        }
    }




}
```